# How can I use rails console to check database's entries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use rails 4 with mysql and have a table named items. 
I run rails generate model

```
rails generate model items
```

I want to check if this model is indeed been mapped to the database table so I ru

```
Items.find(1)
```

and getting

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `1'
```

Comment: You just need to use the singular `Item`, as that's the name of the model class.

Comment: And you need to run `rails console` first

Answer (score 4):

Run `rails console`, then try `Item.find(1)`